# Make NSViews and NSWindows have fixed position

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsview

Im trying to make my NSViews and windows that I create programmatically have a fixed position no matter what the resolution of my screen is and no matter how many displays i have connected to my main desktop.  For example if I have an external monitor or if I decide to change my screen resolution I want the NsRect of my NSView or NSWindow to always appear in the same place.  Would this work?

```
NSRect mainFrame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame]
NSRect helpFrame = NSZeroRect;
helpFrame.origin.x = (mainFrame.size.width - width) / 2.0;
```

would that put the x value of my window always in the center no matter what the resolution is?  I feel that when I connect an external monitor the resolution changes and the middle of the screen is no longer where I want it.  Is `NSScreen mainScreen` the appropriate thing to call?  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you're asking is ambiguous.  What does "same place" mean?

You don't show what `width` is. Assuming it's the width of the window, what you showed will compute an X location that horizontally centers the window on the "main" screen.  However, `-mainScreen` may not do what you think.  If you want the primary display, the one with the menu bar, you want `[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0]`.

However, even if you set the window's frame using the computation shown, that doesn't *keep* it centered if the screen configuration changes.  You need to observe the `NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification` from the application object and recenter it.

By the way, is there a reason you're not using `-[NSWindow center]`?

Comment: how would I go about re centering objects under `NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParametersNotification` ? Is there a simple way to update it?

Comment: If you're OK with the positioning provided by `-[NSWindow center]`, just call that on the relevant window.  Otherwise, compute whatever position you like and call one of the `-setFrame...` methods.